# Connecting Salesforce to OneDrive files per user (external data sources, external data user authentications)

Tags: files-connect

I have a working model for connecting my Salesforce org to my company's OneDrive file repository.  However, I can only get it to work when the "Identity Type" defined in the external data source is set to "Named Principal".  This is not what I want, since the intention is for external/community users to log in and see only their own documents.

I switched the external data source to be "Per User", and I setup the External Data User Authentications. The issue I am running into is that I don't want to select "Start Authentication Flow on Save".  This is because I want external/community users to authenticate themselves when they access the external objects for the first time.

If I check "Start Authentication Flow on Save", then I am prompted to log into OneDrive.  This isn't reasonable for hundreds of external/community users.  So, I leave it unchecked.  The result is an error when I attempt to pull the data from the external object:
**data.api.DataSourceAuthException: Invalid or missing credentials**

I researched this error, and the only tips I could find say to setup the External Data User Authentications, which I already did.

Is it possible to integrate OneDrive with Salesforce so users can only see their own documents?

I suppose a workaround is to use "Named Principal", log into OneDrive as a superuser and then filter the external object results based on the logged in user.  but, I would rather try a declarative way instead.

Thanks,
Jeff